# How to remove cv::RotatedRect after use in opencv..?

Tags: android, opencv

What I am doing is => I'm capturing the image, after that I'm calculating the skew angle of captured image and then I'm rotating that image according to calculated skew angle. Everything is working fine, but the problem is I have used ***cv::RotatedRect***  in my code and because of this my resulting image contains that box also, I wants to remove that box from my resulting image, Anybody has any Idea How can I remove that box..? I'm specifying my code below.. Please help..! Thanks..! [I cant upload my resulting image, because  I am new to StackOverflow and yet I don't have rights to upload the image.]

```
// Function to Find Skew angle.
 double compute_skew(const char* filename)
   {

// Load in grayscale.
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename, 0);

  // Binarize
  cv::threshold(img, img, 225, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

  // Invert colors
  cv::bitwise_not(img, img);

  cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 3));
  cv::erode(img, img, element);

  std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
      if (*it)
        points.push_back(it.pos());

   cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

   double angle = box.angle;
    if (angle < -45.)
      angle += 90.;

    cv::Point2f vertices[4];
      box.points(vertices);
      for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        cv::line(img, vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % 4], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1, CV_AA);

      std::cout << "File **************Angle***************** " << filename << ": " << angle << std::endl;


return angle;
```

}

```
// Function to rotate image image
void deskew(const char* filename, double angle)
 {

    //angle = 90;
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filename, 0);

  cv::bitwise_not(img, img);

  std::vector<cv::Point> points;
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
  cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
    if (*it)
      points.push_back(it.pos());

 cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

 cv::Mat rot_mat = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(box.center, angle, 1);

 cv::Mat rotated;
 cv::warpAffine(img, rotated, rot_mat, img.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);

cv::bitwise_not(rotated, rotated);
imwrite(filename,rotated);
```

}

Comment: I too have the same problem; I am detecting faces using detectMultiscale and am drawing a rectangle over the face in the image; because of this the saved image has this rectangle. Can anyone help??

Comment: why can't you just not draw the rectangle there in the first place?  Or just make a copy of the image and don't draw a rectangle on the copy...